# CSS - Styling on Safari messes up depending on refresh

Tags: css, safari

I am working on a project and have got the styling working on Chrome and Firefox well. The styling on Safari gets messed up (all of the content, but not the background, gets moved down a few hundred pixels) when I refresh by using Apple+R or clicking the refresh button on the browserr. But when I click on the url and press enter to refresh, the styling is perfect.

Why would this happen? How can I make the other Apple+R and the Refresh button act the same as a refresh by clicking enter on the URL?

My safari browser is 7.0.3. It would be very complicated for me to put up my code, and I'm not sure how to recreate this issue.

EDIT: When I refresh the "bad" ways, the styling is in the right place for a split second before everything gets moved down.

EDIT2: I've provided a hack solution. It is in the list of answers below. I refuse to believe that this is the best answer, it definitely isn't one I would recommend. I'm hoping someone else may have a better answer, but if you're stuck as I have been you may want to take a look at it.

Comment: I can only advise you to just start removing elements from your HTML in chunks to see what might be causing it. Same with scripts that are being loaded in the footer or header.

Comment: @chdltest - Just went in and started taking pieces off. Couldn't find anything though. I have solved my problem with what I consider a pretty hack solution. But I've put it in answers. I'm not going to accept it in the hopes that someone might give a better answer.

Comment: I suppose you can't provide a link to the website?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing in the JS console, I saw that `window.location.reload();` would refresh the page the "bad" way while `location = location;` would refresh the page the "good" way.

So I added a couple of hacky checks after page load using jQuery. If my contents div (which was the one that was being affected) did not have its regular height and the browser was Safari, then I'd call `location = location;`. All 3 browsers "look" to be working perfectly, which is good enough for now. I may want to take a big step back and re-plan this page though.

Comment: That is so gimmicky, lol. Too bad you can't provide us with anything to help you with.